# got an unexpected keyword argument in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am work with a recommend function which generate post queryset by same tag in this post.
it work pretty much like this:
when a post page is opend `PostDetailView` will pass parameter `post_pk` to `Sidebar.get_recommend` then way to `Post.recommend_posts`

then i received this error

```
TypeError: recommend_posts() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_pk'
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
    @classmethod
    def recommend_posts(cls, post_pk=None):
        post = cls.queryset.get(pk=post_pk)
        post_tags = [tag for tag in post.tag.all()]
        recommend_list = Post.objects.none()
        for tag in post_tags:
            recommend_list = recommend_list | tag.post_set.all()
        recommend_list = recommend_list.distinct().exclude(pk=post_pk)
        return recommend_list
```

```
class PostDetailView(CommonViewMixin, DetailView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post_pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        context.update({'sidebars':Sidebar.get_recommend(post_pk=post_pk),})
        return context
```

```
class Sidebar(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def content_html(self):
        result = ''
        ...
        ...
        elif self.display_type == self.DISPLAY_RECOMMEND:
            context = {
                'posts': Post.recommend_posts(self.post_pk)[:5]
            }
            result = render_to_string('config/blocks/sidebar_comments.html', context)

        return result

    @classmethod
    def get_recommend(cls, post_pk=None):
        cls.post_pk = post_pk
        return cls.objects.filter(status=cls.STATUS_SHOW).filter(display_type=cls.DISPLAY_RECOMMEND)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 987, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "/home/mark/code/env-typeidea/typeidea/typeidea/config/models.py", line 81, in content_html
    'posts': Post.recommend_posts(self.post_pk)[:5]
TypeError: recommend_posts() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_pk'
```

Comment: you're not showing where the `Post.recommend_posts()` function is called. Also make sure `@classmethod` is indented correctly in your `Post` model

Comment: sorry, my fault, now code is correct

Comment: `@classmethod` is still wrongly indented. Is it correctly indented on your machine? If it is, please fix it here so we know that's not the issue. Next, show us your full stack trace.

Comment: @classmethod wrong only because i forget copy indentation， no problem in actual code. and i put traceback in description now

Comment: Are you sure you're not defining `recommend_posts` somewhere else in `Post`? E.g. as a normal method?

Comment: also, can you `print(self.post_pk)` before your `context = ...`?

Comment: ohhhhh, that is the problem, that is such a foolish mistake,thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you check naming the argument Post.recommend_posts(post_pk=self.post_pk).  Or maybe check if post_pk in Sidebar is a Class variable or an Instance Variable